# Sort list of different types

Tags: haskell

I'd like to sort a list of two different types. To do so I first create a `Wrapper`type, so I can `mappend` both types.

1. Is having a `Wrapper` type the right way here?
2. I'm not clear on how do I do the actual sorting if I'd like to sort by the delta key (i.e. `fooDelta` and `barDelta`)

The code:

```
import           Data.List   (sortBy)
import           Data.Monoid
import           Data.Ord    (comparing)

data Foo = Foo
    { fooLabel :: String
    , fooDelta :: Int
    } deriving (Show, Eq)

data Bar = Bar
    { barLabel   :: String
    , barDelta   :: Int
    , barAnother :: String
    } deriving (Show, Eq)

data Wrapper = WFoo Foo | WBar Bar
    deriving (Show, Eq)

sortTest :: [Wrapper]
sortTest =
    listFoo <> listBar
    where
        listFoo = [WFoo $ Foo "label1" 0, WFoo $ Foo "label2" 2]
        listBar = [WBar $ Bar "label1" 1 "another1"]
```

Comment: What is the ordering that you would like on the elements?

Comment: Oh sorry, I've updated the question with the sorting requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A wrapper type is definitely a good way to do this. Since you simply want to sort your wrapped values based on a constituent `Int` value, you can use `Data.List.sortOn`.

Define a function which extracts the delta value:

```
delta :: Wrapper -> Int
delta (WFoo f) = fooDelta f
delta (WBar b) = barDelta b
```

Then use `sortOn` like this:

```
main :: IO ()
main = print $ sortOn delta sortTest
```

This gives the following output for your example:

```
[WFoo (Foo {fooLabel = "label1", fooDelta = 0}),WBar (Bar {barLabel = "label1", barDelta = 1, barAnother = "another1"}),WFoo (Foo {fooLabel = "label2", fooDelta = 2})]
```

Another way to do this is to define an `Ord` instance for your wrapper type. Then you can simply use `sort` on your `[Wrapper]` list.

Comment: dkasak your great answers and explanation are very appreciated. Thank you for making Haskell more approachable!